# Excluding current folder when using du

Tags: linux, du

I'm trying to read the size of the files in a folder using `du -ah`, but the output keeps showing me the current directory information( `.` ).
I was wondering if there's some flag I can use with du to avoid showing the dot directory info?

```
456K    ./EmptyShield.png
320K    ./FullShield.png
384K    ./HalfShield.png
1.2M    ./Heart.ai
1.2M    ./Shield.ai
3.4M    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any such option. I think the simplest approach is to filter out the line associated with `.`

In the [POSIX specification of `du`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) I have found nothing that states this has to be the last line. Still I expect it to be the last line because `du -ah` must process everything else before it knows the size of `.`. I'm not a programmer, nevertheless I think if `du -ah` wanted to print `.` before some `./whatever…` for any reason, then it would have to deliberately postpone printing `./whatever…` and still process it before printing `.`; such postponing would be extra work. So I am eager to assume `.` is always in the last line because this is natural from the point of view of any implementation, even if the specification says nothing about it. I have never encountered `du` that surprises me in this matter.

To filter out the last line:

```
du -ah | sed '$d'
# or
du -ah | head -n -1    # this usage of head is not portable though
```

Note this does not change what `du -ah` does or prints. To make `du` itself not show the line you need another approach. See below.

---

`.` is the default when there is no operand for `du`. Your `du -ah` is equivalent to `du -ah .`.

To make the tool omit `.` you must not specify `.`. Specify all files inside `./` instead:

```
du -ah ./* ./.[!.]* ./..?*
```

or if your shell supports brace expansion:

```
du -ah ./{,.[!.],..?}*
```

There are some problems with this approach:

- Unmatched globs [will probably stay literal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803/108618) and cause `no such file or directory` error; non-fatal though.
- Too many matches will cause [`argument list too long`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45583/108618) error; fatal.
- The [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) states:

  > A file that occurs multiple times under one file operand and that has a link count greater than 1 shall be counted and written for only one entry. It is implementation-defined whether a file that has a link count no greater than 1 is counted and written just once, or is counted and written for each occurrence. It is implementation-defined whether a file that occurs under one file operand is counted for other file operands.

  This means if there are hardlinked files in `.` then your `du -ah` will count and print just one of the bunch (the "multiple times under one file operand" case). My `du -ah ./* ./.[!.]* ./..?*` may or may not print all of the bunch (the "file that occurs under one file operand is counted for other file operands" case). Even if your `du` prints just one of the bunch, it may be not the same one as from `du -ah` (see the next bullet point).
- The order of patterns affects the output.

  E.g. if `A/foo` and `.B/bar` are the same file then `du -ah` will

  - print `A/foo` and account it for the size of `A`, it won't print `.B/bar` and the size of `B` will be as if `bar` wasn't there;
  - *xor* it will print `.B/bar` and account for `.B`, won't print `A/foo` and won't account for `A`.

  `du -ah ./* ./.[!.]* ./..?*` may print both `A/foo` and `.B/bar` (see the previous bullet point). If it prints just one then it will be `A/foo` because `./*` (matching `./A`) comes before `./.[!.]*` (matching `./.B`). Specifying the patterns in the reverse order will make the tool print `.B/bar` instead.